# My kbhit() is not Working On Mac, Making a PingPong Game

Tags: c++, macos, c++14

I am trying to build a ping-pong game on my mac using C++14 (g++ in terminal) and I am getting this error:

```
use of undeclared identifier 'kbhit'
```

here is the code: https://github.com/DemonJAZ/GamesC

The function is in `GameManager`, class named `Input`.

Comment: Post the relevant code here. Don't expect us to follow your link and browse through your code base.

Answer (score 3):

Since there is no sentence with a squiggly mark in the end, I took a liberty to invent a couple of my own.

> *Why am I getting this error?*

There is no `kbhit` function in the C++ language.

> *Why am I seeing people using it all over the place? Why does it work for them?*

They are using it on Windows. It's a Windows function. You are on Mac OS X.

> *I like to be able to use this function. What should I do?*

There are several options.

1. Develop on and for Windows,
2. Find a *port* (i.e. a re-implementation in a different environment) of this function that works on Unix-based systems. I'm sure someone somewhere wrote one. Start with https://www.google.com/search?q=kbhit+mac and if this doesn't help, try https://www.google.com/search?q=kbhit+linux. In fact https://www.google.com/search?q=kbhit+ncurses will probably return the best results, but it's kinda hard to guess if you don't know exactly what to look for.
3. When in Rome do as Romans do. Write to the widely used Unix terminal API known as curses (you probably want the ncurses version).

Comment: > _It's a Windows function_
It is actually part of 16 bit console helper library for MSDOS

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot it may be coming from there but there's conio.h with kbhit and all that in MSVC that won't ever create MSDOS apps any more.